# Instantiation of an abstract class via initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, abstract-class, language-lawyer

I would like to understand why the compiler allows the following code to compile

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A::A\n";
    }

    virtual void f() const = 0;
};

void g(const A& a)
{
    a.f();
}

int main()
{
    g({});
}
```

It even outputs `A::A` when run.

If I replace `g({})` with `g(A())` it obviously doesn't compile. It complains that `A` is abstract and cannot be instantiated. Both Clang and GCC compile this fine without any warnings. When run both versions print `pure virtual method called` and terminate.

Comment: For once MSVS does the right thing(at least I expect it to be the right thing) and rejects this code.

Comment: Wow, I am actually mesmerized by this. How is this even possible? [Confirmed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f46d7d1c07cee4af). Ran with C++17

Comment: Yeah. this does not make any sense at all why this compiles or should even be compilable. Is this an undefined case in the standard or just a bug which gcc and clang both have implemented?

Comment: Does not compile on g++, gives the error "cannot allocate an object of abstract type A", not sure what causes the difference

Comment: I find it unlikely that this is a bug in both `clang` and `gcc`. Some sort of legacy behaviour, perhaps? An extension of backwards-compatibility?

Comment: @BensonLin Works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbe2229928765771).

Comment: @BensonLin: compiles for me. Which version of GCC do you use?

Comment: The rules for `{}` being legal are quirky.  Looks like implementing those quirky rules left a hole in both gcc and clang.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This looks like a known [g++ bug number 70939](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70939):

> #### creating object of abstract class allowed in all versions of g++
>
> g++ compiles ill formed C++ program successfully
>
> ```
> class A {
> public:
>     A() {
>         printf("A()\n");
>     }
>     virtual void b() const = 0;
> };
> int main() {
>     const A& a{};
>     a.b();
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Your code does the same thing as this line

```
const A& a{}
```

as part of `g({})` invocation.